# Given a set of points, find the plane parallel to plane $p$ where your plane cuts the area in half.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area

Given a set of point $G=\{(x,y,z) | 0 \le x\le2, 0 \le y \le 2, 0 \le z \le xy\}$

for all $x,y>0$

Find the plane $p$ parallel to plane $zy$ whereas you get two areas equal in size

What I did was try triple integration, however I am not sure if I did it correctly.

$$\int_0^x dx \int_0^1 dy \int_0^{xy}dz = \int_x^2 dx \int_0^1 dy \int_0^{xy}dz$$

Solving it, I get the following equation

$2x^2=4$ and because I know $x,y>0$ I get the one answer $x{=\sqrt2}$

Knowing that the plane is parallel to plane $zy$, the answer is simply $x=\sqrt2$

However, how do I know if the answer is correct? Did I understand the triple integral correctly?

Comment: I think you are trying to get two solids with equal volumes, not areas.  Your answer is correct, but it would be better to use a constant (rather than x) in your limits for the variable x.

Comment: Thank you, I have been stuck for the past two days figuring out if this is right or wrong, and yes on paper I used x0 but didnt know how to write it on stackexchange :)